# Django - how to access session status from template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-sessions

i want to add an 'EDIT' link for each posts on index page. but before show this link ; i need to check if session is registered. i mean i need something like this :

```
{% if session.name=='blabla' %}
    <a href="#">Edit</a>
{% endif %}
```

i have  **django.core.context_processors.request** on **template context processors.**

thank you

edit :

here is my detailpage view :

```
def singlePost(request,postslug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=postslug)
    context = {'post':post}
    return render_to_response('detail.html',context,context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

when i try this :

```
def singlePost(request,postslug):
    session=request.session['loggedin']
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=postslug)
    context = {'post':post}
    return render_to_response('detail.html',context,context_instance = RequestContext(request,{'session':'session',}))
```

it gives template syntax error ( render error)

i tried this :

```
{% if request.session.name=='blablabla' %}
```

here is the error :

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /post/viva-barca

Could not parse the remainder: '=='djangoo'' from 'request.session.name=='djangoo''
```

Comment: If you are getting an error you should include the full traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a different way.

```
{% if post.owner == user %}

        <div class="right"><a href="{% url editpost post.id %}">Edit</a></div>

        {% endif %}
```

in this way ; i can control user auth too. because there r many users which have their own accounts and posts which are listed in index.html. if i dont write this control ; x user can edit other y user's post. but now only logged in users can edit their own posts.

and if there is no any logged in user ; the 'EDIT' link is not shown.

Comment: you should have context for User model in your view file to use it in template file.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `django.core.context_processors.request` and the template is rendered with a `RequestContext` then you can access the session off of the request.

```
{% if request.session.name == 'blabla' %}
    <a href="#">Edit</a>
{% endif %}
```

Edit:

A `RequestContext` is used automatically by the [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) shortcut and the generic views. If you are using `render_to_response` is needs to be passed using the `context_instance` argument. This is detailed in the docs for `RequestContext` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext

Comment: render a template with a Request Context? can you explain?

Comment: it didnt work. i think i am doin sth wrong. see my update on question

Comment: it didnt work. no errors. but didnt work. i login to admin page. then return to index page. but cant see 'edit' string. i ve added the view ( second one )

Comment: Nothing in your view is setting `session['name']`

Comment: it worked now. but when i log out : key error 'name' . it must just disappear.